# Удаление всех элементов в QtreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qtreewidget

Подскажите как удалить все элементы в `QTreeWidget`. Не вспомощью `clear()`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        g = ['я'
            ,'не'
            ,'что'
            ,'в'
            ,'и'
            ,'ты'
            ,'это'
            ,'на'
            ,'с'
            ,'он'
            ,'вы'
            ,'да'
            ,'как'
            ,'мы'
            ,'мне'
            ,'а'
            ,'меня']
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, ['..'])
        for i in g:
            j = []
            a = str(i)
            j.append(a)    
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)

        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.DoubleClicked)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)    
        
    def DoubleClicked(self):
        print(self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0))
        self.initUI()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне надо для `FTP` клиента работает это так. пользователь нажимает два раза по папке или по файлу если по папки то он в на нее переходит если по файлу он скачивает.

В данном примере есть список слов, после двойного нажатия список обновляется. Но есть проблема, во время обновления. во второй раз, если использовать `clear()` то. Он выводит ошибку что `self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text` является `None` и не имеет атрибута `.text`

основной код:

```
import sys
import ftplib
import easygui 
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self) 
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&File')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)    
        
        self.server = self.menubar.addMenu('Server')
        self.connectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Connect server', self)
        self.connectAction.setStatusTip('Connect server')
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.connect_FTP_server)
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.connectAction) 

        self.disconnectAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Disconnect server', self)
        self.disconnectAction.setStatusTip('Disconnect server')
        self.disconnectAction.triggered.connect(self.disconnect_FTP_server)
        self.server.addAction(self.disconnectAction) 

        self.updateAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), 'Update list file', self)
        self.updateShortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("F5"), self)
        self.updateShortcut.activated.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.updateAction.setStatusTip('Update list file')
        self.updateAction.triggered.connect(self.ftp_lst)
        self.server.addAction(self.updateAction) 
        
        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)
        # self.grid.addWidget(self.FTP_tree, 199, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        # self.vbox.addLayout(self.grid)
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.uploading_files_to_server)
        # self.grid.addWidget(self.tree, 200, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom) 
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())

        self.filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)
        if QFileInfo(self.filePath).completeSuffix() != '':
            return self.filePath
        else: 
            pass


    def disconnect_FTP_server(self):
        self.ftp.close()
        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(True)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.FTP_tree, 199, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        

    def word_getWelcome(self):
        str1 = self.ftp.getwelcome()
        words = str1.split()


    def connect_FTP_server(self):
        msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
        fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
        title = 'FTP' 
        ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
        
        try:
            self.ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.1" ,"Artem" ,"1204")
            self.ftp.encoding = 'utf-8'
            self.ftp.set_pasv(False)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return self.ftp

    

    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.FTP_tree.clear()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, ['..'])
        self.nlst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.nlst_len = len(self.nlst)
        for i in self.nlst:
            j = []
            j.append(i)    
            j.append(str(self.ftp.size(i)))
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)
            self.FTP_item1.setFlags(self.FTP_item1.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.downloading_from_server)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.FTP_tree, 1, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom) 
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.file_lst = self.ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(self.nlst)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        # self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()


    def openMenu(self, position):
        self.position = position
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        self.delete = QtWidgets.QAction('delete', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.delete)
        self.delete.triggered.connect(self.delete_file)

        self.new_folder = QtWidgets.QAction('new folder', self.menu)
        self.menu.addAction(self.new_folder)
        self.new_folder.triggered.connect(self.newfolder)

        self.rename = QtWidgets.QAction('rename', self.menu)
        self.rename.triggered.connect(self.rename_file)
        self.menu.addAction(self.rename)

        if self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position) != None:
            self.menu.exec_(self.FTP_tree.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.position))
        else:
            pass

    def newfolder(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new folder name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            print(ok)
            self.ftp.mkd(text)
        self.ftp_lst()



    def rename_file(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTPZ',
            'Enter a new file name:')
        a = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position).text(0)
        print(a)
        if ok:
            self.ftp.rename(a, text)
            print(ok)
            self.ftp_lst()

    def delete_file(self):
        self.name_file = self.FTP_tree.itemAt(self.position)
        print(self.name_file)
        self.ftp.delete(self.name_file.text(0))
        self.ftp_lst()

    def dwc(self):
        url = self.ftp.pwd()
        b = -2
        while True:
            if url[b] == '/':
                c = url[:b]
                break
            else:
                b -= 1
        if c == '':
            c = '/'
        return c


    def uploading_files_to_server(self):
        f1 = open(self.filePath, "rb")
        filename = QUrl(self.filePath).fileName() 
        send = self.ftp.storbinary("STOR" + filename, f1)
        f1.close()


    def downloading_from_server(self):
        b = f'{self.ftp.pwd()}/{self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)}'
        c = QUrl(b).fileName()
        
        if self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0) == '..':

            self.ftp.cwd(self.dwc())
            self.ftp_lst()
        
        elif QFileInfo(c).completeSuffix() == '':
            self.ftp.cwd(b)  
            self.ftp_lst()
            
        else:
            way = easygui.diropenbox()
            host_file = os.path.join(
                way, self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0)
            )
    
            try:
                with open(host_file, 'wb') as local_file:
                    self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0), local_file.write)
            except ftplib.error_perm:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, в котором вы хотите это сделать и с какой целью вы хотите это сделать.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Также добавил и основной код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка происходит потому что строка

```
self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.DoubleClicked)
```

записана не в том месте.

Вы при каждом `DoubleClicked` добавляете новый сигнал, 
вот и получается, что один сигнал срабатывает нормально,
и второй срабатывает, но элемент уже удален.

Правильно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)

        tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(15, 5)   # замените на свой воджет
        self.splitter.addWidget(tableWidget)        

        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.DoubleClicked)        
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.i = 1                     # добавил для визуализации, уберете
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        g = [f'item{self.i}-1'
            ,f'item{self.i}-2'
            ,f'item{self.i}-3'
            ,f'item{self.i}-4'
            ,f'item{self.i}-5'
        ]
        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, [f'.. {self.i}'])
        for i in g:
            j = []
            a = str(i)
            j.append(a)    
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)

    def DoubleClicked(self):
        print(self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0))
        self.FTP_tree.clear()

        self.i += 1                 # добавил для визуализации, уберете

        self.initUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Чтобы понять о чем я написал выше, вставьте строку

```
print('\n 1 -->', self.FTP_tree.currentItem())               # +++
```

и вам станет понятно, что происходит.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                                
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect, QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QMenu, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar, QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QShortcut, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect, QFileInfo, Qt, QSize, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.splitter)

        tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(15, 5)   # замените на свой воджет
        self.splitter.addWidget(tableWidget)        

        self.columns = ['Name', 'Size']
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.FTP_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.i = 1                     # добавил для визуализации, уберете

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        g = [f'item{self.i}-1'
            ,f'item{self.i}-2'
            ,f'item{self.i}-3'
            ,f'item{self.i}-4'
            ,f'item{self.i}-5'
        ]

        self.FTP_tree.setHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.FTP_tree.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.FTP_tree.setDisabled(False)
        self.FTP_tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.DoubleClicked)        
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.FTP_tree)

        self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, [f'.. {self.i}'])
        for i in g:
            j = []
            a = str(i)
            j.append(a)    
            self.FTP_item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.FTP_tree, j)

    def DoubleClicked(self):
        print('\n 1 -->', self.FTP_tree.currentItem())               # +++
        print(' 2 -->', self.FTP_tree.currentItem().text(0))
        self.FTP_tree.clear()

        self.i += 1                 # добавил для визуализации, уберете

        self.initUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(640, 480)                    
    ex.show()                              
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]